# How To Determine Buffer Size for MySQL Bulk INSERT

Tags: mysql, sql, bulkinsert

I'm writing a migration that will use bulk insert statements. It searches the DB for certain info & compiles it into a format that's being used in a particular table & writes it using the INSERT method below. The MySQL machines that will be running this all have a max_allowed_packet size of 16MB, which I cannot change.

I'm fairly new at this. I attempted to insert what I have in my buffer when I got to just below 16MB of characters in it. This isn't working. The max_allowed_packet size goes over 16MB & causes problems. The reason why is probably obvious to anyone who knows what they're doing (but not to me).

I need to know how to calculate how many characters I can insert with a given max_allowed_packet size. We're using the INNODB storage engine.

This is more or less what my insert statements look like:

```
INSERT INTO _table_ (col_name1, col_name2, col_name3) 
      VALUES (val1, val2, val3), (val1, val2, val3), (val1, val2, val3)... etc.
```

If I need to give more info, please let me know. At this point I don't really know what to do.

**Edited to clarify the question.**

Comment: Yes MySQL client/server have a max_allowed_packet size which is 16Mb by default but configurable.  This is configued in my.cnf see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/packet-too-large.html

Comment: @Darryl - Thanks. I think I didn't explain my problem very well or didn't use the proper terminology. I do understand where the max_allowed_packet setting is. The issue is that I don't know how to determine how much data I can put into a the insert without exceeding that packet size. Changing the max_allowed_packet size on the servers isn't an option for me.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem and have discovered following with trial and error.

1. max_allowed_packet-1 is maximum number of characters that the query
   can have.
2. empty spaces in query are add to the length of the query

for ex.

```
INSERT INTO _table_ (col_name1) Values('value1')    -- 1
```

is shorter than

```
INSERT INTO _table_ (col_name1   ) Values('value1'    )    -- 2
```

This may seem fairly obvious when thinking in terms of string length, however think of the two as queries and you expect both to behave exactly the same.
If max_allowed_packet is greater than the length of the '1' above and less than '2', then 2 will not execute while 1 runs properly

Comment: Thanks for the edit @bensiu .. I will take care in future

Answer (score 0):

Reading the link I provided and the user comments in the webpage yields a command:

```
show variables like 'max_allowed_packet';
```

This allows a client to ask the server for its configuration setting.

```
Variable_name       Value
max_allowed_packet, 1048576
```

The application is of course in control of the client SQL driver to set it up to match (or be larger).